# Anonymous session data is being carried over for another user

Tags: 8, sessions

I am saving form values to a session variable for anonymous users in a WebformHandler using the following code:

```
$values = $form_state->getValues();
// set session vars
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
$session->set('user_signup_data', $values);
```

I've just discovered that data from a previous submission is sometimes still present for a new (anonymous) user.

Could this confusion perhaps come from users being on the same network, or the fact that they are both anonymous users?

Is there anything special I need to do to prevent this?

Comment: "the fact that they are both anonymous users" ... have a look at private tempstore service. Or use cookies.

Comment: Are you using any type of CDN or caching mechanism?